# Miniprofiler with EF 5 inspecting duplicate queries ( Readers)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have my object-to-object mapping code (using [automapper](http://automapper.org/)) in service layer with lazy-loading enabled:

```
public IEnumerable<TaskViewModel> MapToView(IEnumerable<IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment> models)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment, TaskViewModel>()
                .ForMember(t => t.AssetOrShotName, map => map.MapFrom(t => t.IRAS_PM_Asset_Sequence.AssetShotName))
                .ForMember(t => t.Days, map => map.MapFrom(t => (t.StartDate.HasValue && t.DeadLine.HasValue)
                    ? t.DeadLine.Value.Subtract(t.StartDate.Value).TotalDays
                    : 0.0))
                .ForMember(t => t.DepartmentName, map => map.MapFrom(t => t.IRAS_PM_DepartmentName.DeptName));                

            return models.Select(x => Mapper.Map<IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment, TaskViewModel>(x));
        }
```

And my controller call is:

```
public ActionResult TaskRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? projectId)
    {
        var tasks = projectId.HasValue
            ? _taskRepository.MapToView(_taskRepository.FindBy(x => x.ProjectId == projectId).ToList())
            : _taskRepository.MapToView(_taskRepository.All.ToList());

        return Json(tasks.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When inspecting EF-queries, miniprofiler warns me for duplicate reader queries:
[image: Miniprofiler alert]

What am i doing wrong? please help me to remove redundant readers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on this line:

```
.ForMember(t => t.DepartmentName, map => map.MapFrom(t => t.IRAS_PM_DepartmentName.DeptName));
```

For every `IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment` entity here, you are loading looking up the `IRAS_PM_DepartmentName` that is related to that entity, and getting its department name.

Because of Lazy Loading, these are called one at a time, for every row you are loading.

The solution is to perform [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) on the `IRAS_PM_DepartmentName` entity relates to your base `IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment`. The code to do this remove this:

```
_taskRepository.FindBy(x => x.ProjectId == projectId).ToList();
```

And instead use something like this:

```
_taskRepository.FindBy(x => x.ProjectId == projectId)
               .Include(x => x.IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment)
               .ToList();
```

You can make a similar change to the unfiltered retrieval.

The [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) statement should pull down each of those related items in the initial query, eliminating the need to look each one up subsequently, one at a time.

Comment: Eager loading is good idea, but i am using Repository pattern and repository layer don't understand .Include() method. Should i have to write my own .Include() extension?

Comment: If you want to avoid the N+1 issues that you are facing here, while keeping the same AutoMapper setup, you are going to have to use Eager Loading. And that means adding methods to your repository that return `ObjectQuery<T>` collections onto which you can use the `Include()` extension method.

Comment: Thanks yaakov for your valuable suggestion, i found [this](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/reviewing-my-data-access-using-entity-framework-profiler) with some nice hints. As you have said, `Include()` (or `CreateSourceQuery()`) are for `ObjectQuery<T>` (or `DbSet<T>` or `DbQuery<T>`) not for `IEnumerable<T>`, i am returning tasks with eager-loaded departments by a custom method (alternative to `FindBy()`).

Comment: But, while returning 44 tasks, profiler shows only 11 sql readers (8 of which are duplicate). If it is n+1 issue, shouldn't it be 45 (instead of 11).

Comment: You will end up having one duplicate for each row in this particular data retrieval. MiniProfiler may be showing others as well.

Comment: I tried increasing rows to 60 for `MapToView(IEnumerable<IRAS_PM_TaskAssignment> models)`, it now shows 16 queries (13 being duplicates). I don't know what the issue is, may be some kind of caching on dynamic proxies or else. Each duplicates taking 0.5 to 1.5 ms.